# Как программно определить, какая картинка в данный момент установлена на виджете PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qlabel, слайд-шоу

Программа должна менять картинки при нажатии на кнопки. 
Но при этом, если у меня установлена одна картинка, мне необходимо при нажатии кнопки показать другую, чтобы они шли по очереди.

Думал сделать это через `if`.

Мой код:

```py
i = 1

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.photo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.photo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -18, 1920, 540))
        self.photo.setText("")
        self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("1"))
        self.photo.setScaledContents(False)
        self.photo.setObjectName("photo")
        self.left = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 210, 71, 41))
        self.left.setObjectName("left")
        self.right = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1850, 230, 71, 41))
        self.right.setObjectName("right")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.right.clicked.connect(self.show_next)
        self.left.clicked.connect(self.show_next)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.left.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.right.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def show_next(self):
        global i
        if i == 1:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("2"))
            i += 1
        elif i == 2:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("1"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Глобальные переменные - это зло.

Вот одна из возможных реализаций вашей задачи.

```
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SlidingStackedWidget(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SlidingStackedWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_direction = QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
        self.m_speed = 500
        self.m_animationtype = QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutCubic
        self.m_now = 0
        self.m_next = 0
        self.m_wrap = False
        self.m_pnow = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)
        self.m_active = False

    def setDirection(self, direction):
        self.m_direction = direction

    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        self.m_speed = speed

    def setAnimation(self, animationtype):
        self.m_animationtype = animationtype

    def setWrap(self, wrap):
        self.m_wrap = wrap

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInPrev(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now > 0:
            self.slideInIdx(now - 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInNext(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now < (self.count() - 1):
            self.slideInIdx(now + 1)

    def slideInIdx(self, idx):
        if idx > (self.count() - 1):
            idx = idx % self.count()
        elif idx < 0:
            idx = (idx + self.count()) % self.count()
        self.slideInWgt(self.widget(idx))

    def slideInWgt(self, newwidget):
        if self.m_active:
            return

        self.m_active = True

        _now = self.currentIndex()
        _next = self.indexOf(newwidget)

        if _now == _next:
            self.m_active = False
            return

        offsetx, offsety = self.frameRect().width(), self.frameRect().height()
        self.widget(_next).setGeometry(self.frameRect())

        if not self.m_direction == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = 0, -offsety
            else:
                offsetx = 0
        else:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = -offsetx, 0
            else:
                offsety = 0

        pnext = self.widget(_next).pos()
        pnow = self.widget(_now).pos()
        self.m_pnow = pnow

        offset = QtCore.QPoint(offsetx, offsety)
        self.widget(_next).move(pnext - offset)
        self.widget(_next).show()
        self.widget(_next).raise_()

        anim_group = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(
            self, finished=self.animationDoneSlot
        )

        for index, start, end in zip(
            (_now, _next), (pnow, pnext - offset), (pnow + offset, pnext)
        ):
            animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
                self.widget(index),
                b"pos",
                duration=self.m_speed,
                easingCurve=self.m_animationtype,
                startValue=start,
                endValue=end,
            )
            anim_group.addAnimation(animation)

        self.m_next = _next
        self.m_now = _now
        self.m_active = True
        anim_group.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def animationDoneSlot(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.m_next)
        self.widget(self.m_now).hide()
        self.widget(self.m_now).move(self.m_pnow)
        self.m_active = False
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

# создайте список каких-то своих изображений        
        self.list_icon = [
            "lena.jpg", "Ok.png", "cat.jpg", 'image_test22.jpg', 'im.png',
            "lena.jpg", "Ok.png", "fg.png", 'linux.gif', 'im.png'
        ]

        slidingStacked = SlidingStackedWidget()

        for i in self.list_icon:

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(i).scaled(
                self.width()-20, self.height()-150, 
                Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
                
            color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))
            label.setStyleSheet(
                "QLabel{ background-color: %s; color : white; font: 40pt}"
                % (color.name(),)
            )

            slidingStacked.addWidget(label)        
        
        button_prev = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Previous", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInPrev
        )
        button_next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Next", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInNext
        )

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(button_prev)
        hlay.addWidget(button_next)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)
        lay.addWidget(slidingStacked)

            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_next(self):
        global i
        if i == 1:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("2"))
            i += 1
        elif i == 2:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("1"))
            i=1
```

Возможно, забыл изменить переменную i.

Answer (score -1):

вот все-таки, как это сделать через переменные:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.photo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.photo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -18, 1920, 540))
        self.photo.setText("")
        self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("NPHsMHXrqxw.png"))
        self.photo.setScaledContents(True)
        self.photo.setObjectName("photo")
        self.left = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 210, 71, 41))
        self.left.setObjectName("left")
        self.left.setText("Left")
        self.right = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1850, 230, 71, 41))
        self.left.setObjectName("right")
        self.right.setText("Right")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        
        self.i = 1        

        self.right.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_next(1))
        self.left.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_next(-1))


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.left.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Left"))
        self.right.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Right"))

    def show_next(self, value):

        self.i += value
        if self.i > 3:
            self.i = 1
        elif self.i < 1:
            self.i = 3
            
        if self.i == 2:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("71gEpF2OMb8.png"))

        elif self.i == 3:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("loXBtxufzps.png"))

        elif self.i == 1:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("NPHsMHXrqxw.png"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).