# Как переместить и поменять размер виджетов в этом приложении?

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qlayout, слайд-шоу

У меня есть данный код, однако я не могу в нем разобраться и расставить все виджеты в нем как нужно, а точнее надо установить:

- button_prev(0, 210, 71, 41),
- button_next(1850, 230, 71, 41),
- label(-4, -18, 1920, 540)`.

```
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SlidingStackedWidget(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SlidingStackedWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_direction = QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
        self.m_speed = 500
        self.m_animationtype = QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutCubic
        self.m_now = 0
        self.m_next = 0
        self.m_wrap = False
        self.m_pnow = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)
        self.m_active = False

    def setDirection(self, direction):
        self.m_direction = direction

    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        self.m_speed = speed

    def setAnimation(self, animationtype):
        self.m_animationtype = animationtype

    def setWrap(self, wrap):
        self.m_wrap = wrap

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInPrev(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now > 0:
            self.slideInIdx(now - 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInNext(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now < (self.count() - 1):
            self.slideInIdx(now + 1)

    def slideInIdx(self, idx):
        if idx > (self.count() - 1):
            idx = idx % self.count()
        elif idx < 0:
            idx = (idx + self.count()) % self.count()
        self.slideInWgt(self.widget(idx))

    def slideInWgt(self, newwidget):
        if self.m_active:
            return

        self.m_active = True

        _now = self.currentIndex()
        _next = self.indexOf(newwidget)

        if _now == _next:
            self.m_active = False
            return

        offsetx, offsety = self.frameRect().width(), self.frameRect().height()
        self.widget(_next).setGeometry(self.frameRect())

        if not self.m_direction == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = 0, -offsety
            else:
                offsetx = 0
        else:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = -offsetx, 0
            else:
                offsety = 0

        pnext = self.widget(_next).pos()
        pnow = self.widget(_now).pos()
        self.m_pnow = pnow

        offset = QtCore.QPoint(offsetx, offsety)
        self.widget(_next).move(pnext - offset)
        self.widget(_next).show()
        self.widget(_next).raise_()

        anim_group = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(
            self, finished=self.animationDoneSlot
        )

        for index, start, end in zip(
            (_now, _next), (pnow, pnext - offset), (pnow + offset, pnext)
        ):
            animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
                self.widget(index),
                b"pos",
                duration=self.m_speed,
                easingCurve=self.m_animationtype,
                startValue=start,
                endValue=end,
            )
            anim_group.addAnimation(animation)

        self.m_next = _next
        self.m_now = _now
        self.m_active = True
        anim_group.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def animationDoneSlot(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.m_next)
        self.widget(self.m_now).hide()
        self.widget(self.m_now).move(self.m_pnow)
        self.m_active = False
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

# создайте список каких-то своих изображений        
        self.list_icon = [
            "1.png", "2.png", '3.png',
        ]

        slidingStacked = SlidingStackedWidget()

        for i in self.list_icon:

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(i))
            label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -18, 1920, 540))
            label.setScaledContents(True)
                
            color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))
            label.setStyleSheet(
                "QLabel{ background-color: %s; color : white; font: 40pt}"
                % (color.name(),)
            )
            label.setGeometry(-4, -18, 1920, 540)
            

            slidingStacked.addWidget(label)        
        
        button_prev = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Previous", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInPrev
        )
        button_prev.move(0, 210)
        button_prev.resize(71, 41)
        
        button_next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Next", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInNext
        )
        

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(button_prev)
        hlay.addWidget(button_next)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)
        lay.addWidget(slidingStacked)

            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(1920, 1080)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот код я готовил для вас и публиковал как ответ в вашем [**вопросе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1379485), который вы  приняли, а затем отменили прием и добавили свой не очень удачный ответ.

Теперь вы начинаете использовать этот код и я надеюсь, что вы вернетесь к тому вопросу и примите правильное решение.

Теперь по текущему вопросу. Абсолютное позиционирование не самое хорошее решение. Я покажу вам как поменяв `Layout` можно получить желаемый результат.

```
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SlidingStackedWidget(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SlidingStackedWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_direction = QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
        self.m_speed = 500
        self.m_animationtype = QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutCubic
        self.m_now = 0
        self.m_next = 0
        self.m_wrap = False
        self.m_pnow = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)
        self.m_active = False

    def setDirection(self, direction):
        self.m_direction = direction

    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        self.m_speed = speed

    def setAnimation(self, animationtype):
        self.m_animationtype = animationtype

    def setWrap(self, wrap):
        self.m_wrap = wrap

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInPrev(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now > 0:
            self.slideInIdx(now - 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def slideInNext(self):
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if self.m_wrap or now < (self.count() - 1):
            self.slideInIdx(now + 1)

    def slideInIdx(self, idx):
        if idx > (self.count() - 1):
            idx = idx % self.count()
        elif idx < 0:
            idx = (idx + self.count()) % self.count()
        self.slideInWgt(self.widget(idx))

    def slideInWgt(self, newwidget):
        if self.m_active:
            return

        self.m_active = True

        _now = self.currentIndex()
        _next = self.indexOf(newwidget)

        if _now == _next:
            self.m_active = False
            return

        offsetx, offsety = self.frameRect().width(), self.frameRect().height()
        self.widget(_next).setGeometry(self.frameRect())

        if not self.m_direction == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = 0, -offsety
            else:
                offsetx = 0
        else:
            if _now < _next:
                offsetx, offsety = -offsetx, 0
            else:
                offsety = 0

        pnext = self.widget(_next).pos()
        pnow = self.widget(_now).pos()
        self.m_pnow = pnow

        offset = QtCore.QPoint(offsetx, offsety)
        self.widget(_next).move(pnext - offset)
        self.widget(_next).show()
        self.widget(_next).raise_()

        anim_group = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(
            self, finished=self.animationDoneSlot
        )

        for index, start, end in zip(
            (_now, _next), (pnow, pnext - offset), (pnow + offset, pnext)
        ):
            animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
                self.widget(index),
                b"pos",
                duration=self.m_speed,
                easingCurve=self.m_animationtype,
                startValue=start,
                endValue=end,
            )
            anim_group.addAnimation(animation)

        self.m_next = _next
        self.m_now = _now
        self.m_active = True
        anim_group.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def animationDoneSlot(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.m_next)
        self.widget(self.m_now).hide()
        self.widget(self.m_now).move(self.m_pnow)
        self.m_active = False
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

# создайте список каких-то своих изображений        
        self.list_icon = [
            "Ok.png", "ball.png", 'im.png',
        ]

        slidingStacked = SlidingStackedWidget()

        for i in self.list_icon:

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(i))
            label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -18, 1920, 540))
            label.setScaledContents(True)
                
            color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))
            label.setStyleSheet(
                "QLabel{ background-color: %s; color : white; font: 40pt}"
                % (color.name(),)
            )
            label.setGeometry(-4, -18, 1920, 540)

            slidingStacked.addWidget(label)        
        
        button_prev = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Previous", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInPrev
        )
#        button_prev.move(0, 210)
#        button_prev.resize(71, 41)
        button_prev.setFixedSize(71, 41)                             # +++
        
        button_next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Next", pressed=slidingStacked.slideInNext
        )
        button_next.setFixedSize(71, 41)                             # +++

#        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
#        hlay.addWidget(button_prev)
#        hlay.addWidget(button_next)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        
#        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
#        lay.addLayout(hlay)
#        lay.addWidget(slidingStacked)
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)                  # +++
        lay.addWidget(button_prev, 0, 0)                             # +++
        lay.addWidget(slidingStacked, 0, 1)                          # +++
        lay.addWidget(button_next, 0, 2)                             # +++
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(1920, 1080)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пытаюсь добавить смену изображений по таймеру, но он просто не работает, при этом ошибок не вылазит (при срабатывании таймера должна выполняться функция `pressed=slidingStacked.slideInNext`.

Comment: @cor3 если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Приведите пример, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.